# Clarification about completeness of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

This is probably a very silly question but it bothers me for some time.

We define a metric space $X$ to be complete if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges to some point in $X$.

But any metric space $X$ is closed in itself, so every convergent sequence in $X$ has its limit in $X$. From that I would say that when we check if $X$ is complete, it suffices to check that any Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges because *if* it converges, then it will converge in $X$.

However...

> consider for example the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$,
>   $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$. Take $(f_n)_{n\geq1}$ given
>   by
>
> $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
> 0,&0\leq x\leq\frac12\\
> n\left(x-\frac12\right),&\frac 12<x\leq \frac 12+\frac1n\\
> 1,&\frac12+\frac1n<x\leq 1\;.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> This is continuous for
>   each $n\geq 1$ and so in $C([a,b],\mathbb R)$.  We can show that it is
>   a Cauchy sequence and that it converges in the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm to
>   $f$ defined by $f(x)=1$ when $x\in(1/2,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

If my reasoning above were correct, then we would stop now and say that $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is complete, which of course it isn't because the $f$ we found above is not continuous.

I think that the problem  has to do with the universe we are in. Because if we consider $C[0,1]$ as just a subset of $R[0,1]$ (where this is the set of Riemann integrable functions on $[0,1]$), then of course it is not closed in $R[0,1]$. But we are not doing that, we are just referring to $C[0,1]$, or more generally to the metric space $X$ and assume that $X$ is the "universe."

So what am I missing here?

Comment: The space in your example is $C([0,1],\Bbb R)$, and in that space your sequence does *not* converge: there is no $f\in C([0,1],\Bbb R)$ such that $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\to f$.

Comment: As I see it, it does converge; it's just that its limit is not in $C[0,1]$. I think I see what my issue is. If our universe is $X$, then $x_n$ (if it converges) can only converge in $X$. So, in my example, we either think that our universe is $C[0,1]$ and say that there is no $f$ such that $f_n\to f$, or we say that the our universe is $R[0,1]$ and then there is $f$ such that $f_n\to f$ but $f\notin C[0,1]$. But in the latter case, there is no problem because $C[0,1]$ is not closed in $R[0,1]$. Is this right?

Comment: I don’t disagree on the facts, but I do disagree on the terminology. If you are working n the space $C([0,1],\Bbb R)$, the sequence does not converge: the indicator function of $\left(\frac12,1\right]$ in $[0,1]$ effectively does not exist. If you are working in $R[0,1]$, it does converge, but not to a point of $C([0,1],\Bbb R)$, thereby showing that $C([0,1],\Bbb R)$ is neither complete as a subspace of $R[0,1]$ nor closed in $R[0,1]$. (And of course there is a theorem that says that these two observations are equivalent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian's comments are spot on. Let me add a little (too long for a comment): Properties like "Cauchy" or "convergent" depend on the metric space you're living in. It doesn't make sense to say that the sequence $(3, 3.1, 3.14, . . . )$ converges or doesn't converge - you have to say what metric space you're in. In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, this does converge; in $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric, it doesn't. And the sequence isn't even Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric $d(x, y)=1$!

Usually, of course, we just say things like "$S$ is Cauchy" - but this is a quirk of natural language. Technically, we should say what space we're living in, but we don't when it's clear from context.

There is, however, a useful sense in which Cauchy-ness is "more absolute" than convergence: namely, if $S$ is a sequence in a metric space $M$, and $N$ is a larger metric space, then $S$ is Cauchy in $M$ iff $S$ is Cauchy in $N$. This is not true for convergence. In particular, Cauchy-ness depends only on the distances between the points in the sequence itself; convergence depends on the "rest" of the space.

There is a precise sense in which every Cauchy sequence in a metric space $M$ is convergent "somewhere" - namely, in the *completion* of $M$! But this shift in the underlying space is important.

Comment: People often confuse convergent sequence with Cauchy sequence . A convergent sequence in a space S is a Cauchy sequence in S with a limit point in S. But a Cauchy sequence in S  may fail to have a limit point in S.